# Get result from meta_query() between two numbers

Tags: meta-query

I  have value like :-

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-area'] ) ) {
    $f = $_GET['filter-area'];
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $f, $matches);
    foreach($matches as $key) {
        $first_val = $key[0];
        $second_val = $key[1];
    }
}
```

Now i need to search to get all date between this two values.

So, I tried this way, but it take one value.

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-area'] ) ) {
    $meta[] = array(
        'key'       => REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX . 'attributes_area',
        'value'     => $first_val,
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
    );
}
```

How can search by tow value

Answer (score 15):

Multiple meta values can be compared with `BETWEEN` with an *array* value:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX .'attributes_area',
        'value'   => array( $first_val, $second_val ),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ), // inner array.
), // outer array.
```

You can see this in [Developer Doc.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: in case 2,2.9 & 3,3.9 2 value how to pass ?

Comment: In my case I had to pass `$first_val` and `$second_val` in `floatval()` to make it work.

Comment: Anyone looking at this solution who's wondering why your `meta_query` doesn't work, make sure you have nested arrays (`array( array( ... ))`) in `meta_query`. Don't ask me how long it took to notice that part...