# meta_query Array

Tags: meta-query, pre-get-posts

(by using `$query->set( 'meta_key', 'start_date' );` or `$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query_array );`) ...

how can I send a array of dates in order to wordpress understand that the post as multiple dates and so, should be displayed several times in a chronological order list ?

I try since days to understand the problem and I can't figured out.

I found a solution by separating dates in differents child posts, but as a event (post) as sometimes 20 dates, it generate 20 posts just for a date in a acf field.

Is there a clever way to do it ?

Thanks A LOT !
-Nicolas.

Comment: Can't you use `BETWEEN` in your meta query for this? ([similar to this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215519))

Comment: a post cannot appear multiple times in a `WP_Query` results, you would have to do the processing duplication and sorting in PHP

Comment: ;( Thank you for the information. Means I should make on my own php and mysql query ?

Comment: ... and what is the approach when they dev a calendar ? do they multiply posts ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you wnat do is :

`update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, serialize($meta_value));`

or to create :

`add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, serialize($meta_value));`

or to delete :

`delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key);`

Comment: it seems there no solution, as long as you can't display twice a post on a WP_query.

Comment: well if the taks is alter or create wp_postmeta that is the right way and  100% sure that will works